# device change password form not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I googled it but not got solution. I cant see change password form. (edit_user_password_path) it shows the message "you are already logged in" (Most probably flash[:error] and redirects to dashboard page. I am using rails 4 and device 3.5

User is my device model and I am using users controller as well (extend from ApplicationController) as I want to handle CRUD operations on User on my own.  I am not using :registerable module of device.

my routes file looks like

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'u'
resources :users do
    get 'manage_resource'
    post 'manage_resource'
    get 'profile'    
  end
```

Comment: Did you try signing out and then visit the change password form?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below snippet to your `routes.rb` file

`devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]

as :user do
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'

  put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            end`

You should then be able to access `edit_user_registration_path`

Thanks to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password